# nginx https to 9443

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I have owncloud on my raspberry pi. I was reading nginx wiki about redirect http to https and I can't get it done. I want to use 9443 port for that

Could you please see my config and look what I'm doing wrong.

```
    server {
    listen 9443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:9443 ssl default_server;
    server_name domain.site;
    ssl_certificate     /home/pi/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/pi/ssl/server.key;

    error_page 497 https://$host:9443$request_uri;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my working config below.

```
server {
        listen 80;                      #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:80;                 #Listen on IPv6
        server_name www.loganmarchione.com loganmarchione.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;           #Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl spdy default_server;             #Listen on IPv4
        listen [::]:443 ssl spdy default_server;        #Listen on IPv6
        server_name www.loganmarchione.com loganmarchione.com;

        ssl on;
        #ssl stuff here....
        #rest of config here...
}
```

In the first server block, I allow connections on port 80, then do a 301 redirect to port 443. In your case, it would be 9443. A few things:

- Add `ssl on;` to your nginx config
- Don't forget to open 9443 in your firewall
- Reload Nginx after any config changes `sudo service nginx reload`

Comment: Logan, the server that you redirect "https://$host$request_uri;" responds both IPv4 and IPv6?

I need to get one connection in IPv6 and redirect to one server with IPv4.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, you'll probably need to ask a separate question.